# Flutter how to Fix container on a top

Tags: flutter

I don't use navbar in my app I have created a custom navbar but the issue is it's not fixed. mean when i scroll page navbar also scroll down. I need to fix it so it can be stick on top.

My code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

enum BottomIcons { Home, Favorite, Search, Account }

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  double xOffset = 0;
  double yOffset = 0;
  double scaleFactor = 1;

  bool isDrawerOpen = false;

  int currentIndex = 0;
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  BottomIcons bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Home;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    double Height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double Width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var bottomNavigationBar;
    return AnimatedContainer(
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(xOffset, yOffset, 0)
          ..scale(scaleFactor)
          ..rotateY(isDrawerOpen ? -0.5 : 0),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(isDrawerOpen ? 40 : 0.0)),
        child: Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  BottomBar(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Home;
                        });
                      },
                      bottomIcons:
                          bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Home ? true : false,
                      icons: EvaIcons.home,
                      text: "Home"),
                  BottomBar(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Favorite;
                        });
                      },
                      bottomIcons:
                          bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Favorite ? true : false,
                      icons: EvaIcons.heartOutline,
                      text: "Favorite"),
                  BottomBar(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Search;
                        });
                      },
                      bottomIcons:
                          bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Search ? true : false,
                      icons: EvaIcons.search,
                      text: "Search"),
                  BottomBar(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Account;
                        });
                      },
                      bottomIcons:
                          bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Account ? true : false,
                      icons: EvaIcons.personOutline,
                      text: "Account"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: Height * 0.1,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("images/nav.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          isDrawerOpen
                              ? Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        xOffset = 0;
                                        yOffset = 0;
                                        scaleFactor = 1;
                                        isDrawerOpen = false;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.03,
                                      width: Width * 0.06,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: AssetImage("images/ross.png"),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        xOffset = 280;
                                        yOffset = 150;
                                        scaleFactor = 0.6;
                                        isDrawerOpen = true;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.03,
                                      width: Width * 0.06,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: AssetImage("images/ic.png"),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                          Container(
                            width: Width * 0.25,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.03,
                                width: Width * 0.06,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage("images/i2.png"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: Width * 0.04,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.03,
                                width: Width * 0.06,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage("images/i1.png"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: Width * 0.06,
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        RichText(
                          text: new TextSpan(
                            // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                            // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                              new TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Popular ',
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 22)),
                              new TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Categories',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: Width * 0.1,
                          height: Height * 0.05,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/more.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Color(0xffECF0F1),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    child: GridView(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisSpacing: 1.5,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 1.5,
                        crossAxisCount: 4,
                      ),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.01,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat1.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.008,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Computer Hardware',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.01,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat2.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.008,
                              ),
                              Text('Computer Software',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.01,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat3.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.008,
                              ),
                              Text('Internet', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.01,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat4.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.008,
                              ),
                              Text('Mobile / Table & iPad',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.01,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat5.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.008,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Printer & Scanner',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.01,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat6.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.008,
                              ),
                              Text('CCTV Cameras', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.01,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat7.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.008,
                              ),
                              Text('Smart TV/Home Theater',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.01,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat8.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Height * 0.008,
                              ),
                              Text('E-Learning', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: Height * 0.015,
                  ),
                  CarouselSlider(
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      autoPlay: true,
                      aspectRatio: 2,
                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                      enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
                    ),
                    items: imageSliders,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        RichText(
                          text: new TextSpan(
                            // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                            // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                              new TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Service ',
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 22)),
                              new TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Deals',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: Width * 0.1,
                          height: Height * 0.05,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/see.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: CarouselSlider(
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          disableCenter: true,
                          enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                          viewportFraction: 0.7,
                          enlargeCenterPage: false,
                          height: Height * 0.21,
                        ),
                        items: list
                            .map((item) => Container(
                                  child: Image.asset(item),
                                ))
                            .toList(),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

This is my code I am using a simple column for the whole screen but the issue is in the column I need to fixed the container and scroll the other container.

Comment: Have you tried using `Stack()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The custom AppBar was a child of the SingleChildScrollView itself. Hence, it scrolled. Now, it is a child of a stack which persistently sticks to the top, hence won't scroll.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

enum BottomIcons { Home, Favorite, Search, Account }

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  double xOffset = 0;
  double yOffset = 0;
  double scaleFactor = 1;

  bool isDrawerOpen = false;

  int currentIndex = 0;
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  BottomIcons bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Home;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    double Height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double Width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var bottomNavigationBar;
    return AnimatedContainer(
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(xOffset, yOffset, 0)
          ..scale(scaleFactor)
          ..rotateY(isDrawerOpen ? -0.5 : 0),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(isDrawerOpen ? 40 : 0.0)),
        child: Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  BottomBar(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Home;
                        });
                      },
                      bottomIcons:
                      bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Home ? true : false,
                      icons: EvaIcons.home,
                      text: "Home"),
                  BottomBar(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Favorite;
                        });
                      },
                      bottomIcons:
                      bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Favorite ? true : false,
                      icons: EvaIcons.heartOutline,
                      text: "Favorite"),
                  BottomBar(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Search;
                        });
                      },
                      bottomIcons:
                      bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Search ? true : false,
                      icons: EvaIcons.search,
                      text: "Search"),
                  BottomBar(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          bottomIcons = BottomIcons.Account;
                        });
                      },
                      bottomIcons:
                      bottomIcons == BottomIcons.Account ? true : false,
                      icons: EvaIcons.personOutline,
                      text: "Account"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              RichText(
                                text: new TextSpan(
                                  // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                                  // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  children: <TextSpan>[
                                    new TextSpan(
                                        text: 'Popular ',
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 22)),
                                    new TextSpan(
                                        text: 'Categories',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: Width * 0.1,
                                height: Height * 0.05,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage("images/more.png"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Color(0xffECF0F1),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          child: GridView(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisSpacing: 1.5,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 1.5,
                              crossAxisCount: 4,
                            ),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.01,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.04,
                                      child: Image.asset('images/cat1.png'),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.008,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Computer Hardware',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.01,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.04,
                                      child: Image.asset('images/cat2.png'),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.008,
                                    ),
                                    Text('Computer Software',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.01,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.04,
                                      child: Image.asset('images/cat3.png'),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.008,
                                    ),
                                    Text('Internet', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.01,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.04,
                                      child: Image.asset('images/cat4.png'),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.008,
                                    ),
                                    Text('Mobile / Table & iPad',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.01,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.04,
                                      child: Image.asset('images/cat5.png'),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.008,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Printer & Scanner',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.01,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.04,
                                      child: Image.asset('images/cat6.png'),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.008,
                                    ),
                                    Text('CCTV Cameras', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.01,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.04,
                                      child: Image.asset('images/cat7.png'),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.008,
                                    ),
                                    Text('Smart TV/Home Theater',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.01,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: Height * 0.04,
                                      child: Image.asset('images/cat8.png'),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: Height * 0.008,
                                    ),
                                    Text('E-Learning', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: Height * 0.015,
                        ),
                        CarouselSlider(
                          options: CarouselOptions(
                            autoPlay: true,
                            aspectRatio: 2,
                            enlargeCenterPage: true,
                            enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
                          ),
                          items: imageSliders,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              RichText(
                                text: new TextSpan(
                                  // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                                  // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  children: <TextSpan>[
                                    new TextSpan(
                                        text: 'Service ',
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 22)),
                                    new TextSpan(
                                        text: 'Deals',
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: Width * 0.1,
                                height: Height * 0.05,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage("images/see.png"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: CarouselSlider(
                              options: CarouselOptions(
                                disableCenter: true,
                                enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                                viewportFraction: 0.7,
                                enlargeCenterPage: false,
                                height: Height * 0.21,
                              ),
                              items: list
                                  .map((item) => Container(
                                child: Image.asset(item),
                              ))
                                  .toList(),
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(top: 0,left: 0, child: Container(
                  height: Height * 0.1,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("images/nav.png"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        isDrawerOpen
                            ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                xOffset = 0;
                                yOffset = 0;
                                scaleFactor = 1;
                                isDrawerOpen = false;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: Height * 0.03,
                              width: Width * 0.06,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage("images/ross.png"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                            : Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                xOffset = 280;
                                yOffset = 150;
                                scaleFactor = 0.6;
                                isDrawerOpen = true;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: Height * 0.03,
                              width: Width * 0.06,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage("images/ic.png"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: Width * 0.25,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: Height * 0.03,
                              width: Width * 0.06,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage("images/i2.png"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: Width * 0.04,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: Height * 0.03,
                              width: Width * 0.06,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage("images/i1.png"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: Width * 0.06,
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```